# Problem with filter in my search form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have search form to list properties/ads through certain criteria. My search form works but I am not getting desired results when I search with multiple filters. I have three types of filters. Property bid ask (demand, offer), Porperty payment (buy, rent), Property type (house, flat, garage). For example when I click to search by demand, buy, house it returns one result where demand, buy, house exist and two more where buy and house exist but there the third parameter is offer. I am truying to accomplish that the filter fulfils all three conditions and not just two. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

CategoryController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Property;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('categories.search', compact('data'));
    }

    public function search($propertyBidAsk, $propertyPayment, $propertyType, $city, $price, $quadrature, Request $request, Property $property)
    {
        $category = $property->category;

        if (!empty($request->propertyBidAsk)) {

           $property = Property::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
           $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyBidAsk . '%');
           })->get();
        }

        if (!empty($request->propertyPayment)) {

            $property = Property::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyPayment . '%');
           })->get();
        }

        if (!empty($request->propertyType)) {

            $property = Property::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyType . '%');
            })->get();
        }

        $results = $property;

        return view('categories.search', compact('category', 'results'));
    }
}
```

search.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
<div class="py-5 text-center">
  <h2>Search</h2>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-md-center">

  <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
    <div>

      @if(isset($results))
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <th>Property Bid Ask</th>
            <th>Property Payment</th>
            <th>Property Type</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach ($results as $result)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $result->category[0]->category }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result->category[1]->category }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result->category[2]->category }}</td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      @endif

    <form id="searchForm" method="GET" action="/search">

      <div class="row">

      <hr class="mb-4">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-6">
          <h5>Payment</h4>
          <div class="d-block my-3">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="offer" name="propertyBidAsk" value="offer" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="offer">offer</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="demand" name="propertyBidAsk" value="demand" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="demand">demand</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 mb-6">
        <h5>Property payment</h4>
          <div class="d-block my-3">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
               <input id="buy" name="propertyPayment" value="buy" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="buy">buy</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="rent" name="propertyPayment" value="rent" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="rent">rent</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5 mb-6">
          <h5>Property type</h4>
            <div class="d-block my-3 ">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="house" name="propertyType" value="house" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="house">Kucahouse/label>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="flat" name="propertyType" value="flat" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="flat">flat</label>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="garage" name="propertyType" value="garage" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="garage">garage</label>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    <hr class="mb-4">

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Search</button>

  </form>

  <script>
    var onSubmitFunc = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      if( e.stopImmediatePropagation ){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }

      var propertyBidAsk = this["propertyBidAsk"].value.trim() || 0;
      var propertyPayment = this["propertyPayment"].value.trim() || 0;
      var propertyType = this["propertyType"].value.trim() || 0;

      url = propertyBidAsk.length === 0 ? '' : ( '/' + encodeURIComponent(propertyBidAsk) );
      url += propertyPayment.length === 0 ? '' : ( '/' +  encodeURIComponent(propertyPayment) );
      url += propertyType.length === 0 ? '' : ( '/' + encodeURIComponent(propertyType) );

      window.location.href = this.action + url;

    }

    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var srch = document.getElementById("searchForm");
    srch.addEventListener('submit', onSubmitFunc, false);
    }, false );

  </script>

     </div>

  </div>

</div>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to conditionally add multiple filters on a query at the same time, you can start the query at the top, then add the filters, and finally get the result at the end:

```
$query = Property::query();
if (!empty($request->propertyBidAsk)) {
    $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyBidAsk . '%');
    });
}
if (!empty($request->propertyPayment)) {
    $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyPayment . '%');
    });
}
if (!empty($request->propertyType)) {
    $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('category', 'like', '%' . $request->propertyType . '%');
    });
}
$property = $query->get();
```

Comment: With this when I select some multiple filters and click submit I get empty table (no results), and there should be something.

Comment: @Gacho Then it means there are no results based on those filters combined and there are perhaps other things going wrong. How are the categories saved to the properties? Are they in a different table? Or are they just a field of a Property? If it is the second, you can remove the `$query->whereHas`.

Comment: There are results for certain. Tables are properties (id, city, price), category_property (id, category_id, property_id), categories (id, category, priority). Relationship is many to many and everything there works. Also when I search by individual filter it works, I just get empty results when I combine filters

Comment: @Gacho I updated my answer. I guess my previous answer was trying to match a single category to all 3 filters instead of checking different categories. The idea of the answer stays the same though, start a query at the top and then conditionally add the filters and then get the result.

Comment: That's it. Works!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overwriting the variable `$property` in this case if multiple condition getting true then even if your first query runs then it will replace all data in second `if condition` 
To solve such problem try to store your all three query `result of ->get()` in array and return that array of data.
You must first assign an empty array at the top and whenever the condition gets true store that data in array accordingly.

Comment: Can you help me with code? I understand the idea, just can't get the code to work

Comment: $property = []; at the top and in each if block replace $property by $property[] @Gacho

Comment: Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance.  I get this error when submit form.